# Mvc Route 404 When Passing in id through URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

let me start with explaining what I am trying to do. I have a form with a drop down where on the change of the value  triggers a label text to change. To do this I attached a onchange script event to fire off.

```
 <select onchange="ChangeLabel()" id="ContainerValue" asp-for="Container" class="form-control"/>
```

The Label

```
<label id="AddressLabel" asp-for="Container" class="control-label"/>
```

The script it calls is

```
 <script>
    function ChangeLabel() {
        var val = $('#ContainerValue').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Rundown/GetLabel/' + val ,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (labelText) {
                $("#AddressLabel").html(labelText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

So I create a action in my controller called GetLabel with a parameter id.

```
[HttpGet]
// GET: Rundown/GetLabel/5
public string GetLabel(int id)
{
    return "x";
}
```

So I am pretty sure I am using default routing that's created on setup of project. As far as I know I didn't mess with this.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Now when I change the selection in the drop down the change request gets fired of and a request is made to `/Rundown/GetLabel/1` but it returns a 404 error. Just for testing purposes I noticed that if I did `/Rundown/GetLabel/?id=1` I would hit my GetLabel action and would get back my `"x"` string value. Any idea why I am not seeing my action get hit with the normal
`[controller]/[action]/[id]` routing I would of expected to work?

The only other related information I can think of is a route in a fixture above the controller class.

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class RundownController : Controller
```

Comment: Any feedback regarding the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364899/5233410)

Comment: I am currently at work so I can not test your solution. I had not tried your method yet. The only thing that comes to mind is that I did not see any need to add the `[HttpGet("{id}")]` on the out of the box actions that came already premade, specifically, I am thinking of the `AccountController`. If my memory is correct you can modify a account by doing `/Account/Edit/<account id>` or view the details of a account by doing `/Account/Details/<account id>`. My memory could be wrong. I just didn't understand why mine differed from the default.

Comment: Yes but that is when using convention-based routing. From the time you add a route attribute to the controller things change with how the routes a matched. I'll add a reference link to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing attribute and convention-based routes which is causing a conflict.

The attribute route will take priority here over the convention-based route and since you do not have a route template for the action parameter it is not being found.

Add a route template for the action

```
Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class RundownController : Controller {

    // GET: Rundown/GetLabel/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]        
    public string GetLabel(int id) {
        return "x";
    }

}
```

Having the attribute route on the controller and just the `HttpGet` on the action meant that the URL would have looked like

```
Rundown/GetLabel?id=5
```

By including the route template parameter `[HttpGet("{id}")]` you get the desired behavior.

An alternative is to remove the `Route("[controller]/[action]")]` from the top of the controller and allow the default routing definition from the startup `MapRoute`

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: I will update the answer to include that to make it a more complete answer

Answer (score 1):

You are using GET , so you need to change your route attribute as ->

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("RunDown/GetLabel/{id}")]
public string GetLabel(int id)
{
  return "x";
}
```

You need to write this above you action method.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this solution this did work as well. I selected the other answer because it was a more complete answer and had cited sources.

Comment: Hey @DTagg , Happy to hear that your problem has been solved.Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I think having just went through a similar issue it's worth pointing out that your route parameter has to match your function parameter this can also be a reason you get a 404.